# 'AssertionError' object has no attribute 'message'

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, django-forms, django-oscar

I'm dealing with form in django that once its filled sends an email to the user but im getting the following error:

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMweb.png)

I have checked in my code and my problem comes from this function:

```
def send_manually_exception_email(request, e):
  exc_info = sys.exc_info()
  reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
  subject = e.message.replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')[:989]
  message = "%s\n\n%s" % (
    '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)),
    reporter.filter.get_request_repr(request)
  )
  mail.mail_admins(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=reporter.get_traceback_html())
```

What can I do?

Comment: `e.message` does *not* per se exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exception object `e` does *not* per se has a `message` attribute. You can for example retrieve it if there is such attribute, and use the empty string if there is no such attribute with [**`getattr(…)`** [python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
def send_manually_exception_email(request, e):
  exc_info = sys.exc_info()
  reporter = ExceptionReporter(request, is_email=True, *exc_info)
  subject = getattr(e, 'message', '').replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')[:989]
  message = "%s\n\n%s" % (
    '\n'.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)),
    reporter.filter.get_request_repr(request)
  )
  mail.mail_admins(subject, message, fail_silently=True, html_message=reporter.get_traceback_html())
```

Answer (score 7):

Although better than crashing, OP probably doesn't want to generate an email with a blank subject line.  You can just use the string representation of the error, eg:

```
print(e)
print(f'Function x gave error {e}')
```

In OP's code, it may be good enough to set:

```
subject = str(e)
```

Or use this as an alternative if the error does not have a message:

```
subject = getattr(e, 'message', str(e)).replace('\n', '\\n').replace('\r', '\\r')[:989]
```